# Unexpected response from import service: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: jss

I have version 9.0 update 2 and am working with the sample JSS app. I used the this same app on an earlier environment which was setup as Standalone and had no issues. This is a remote deploy to a scaled environment. When I attempt the command -jss deploy items - I get the following error.

Unexpected response from import service: 
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

This is the scjssconfig.json file I am currently using.

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "C:\\sc9_install\\my-sitecore-jss",
    "apiKey": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}",
    "deploySecret": "",
    "deployUrl": "https://sitecore-scaled/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "my-sitecore-jss"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like the SSL certificate on your remote instance is not trusted. Node does not use Windows' cert store, so if it's a trusted cert there it will not be trusted in the JSS CLI.

You can use the `--acceptCertificate [cert thumbprint]` parameter to make the CLI trust a specific SSL certificate during deployment. To make this easier, consider placing it as an npm script in your package.json (thus running it something like `npm run deploy-items-to-scaled` or whatever you named the script)

Comment: Just in case if @Kam's solution with `--acceptCertificate` doesn't work, consider switching `deployUrl` to `http` from `https` (may require some Sitecore configuration). "Works on my machine" :)

Comment: @AlexShyba's Solution works for me! :-)

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me as well :)

Answer (score 4):

I tried with http but could not succeed. Got below error.

```
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Not Found
Body: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>
```

With https it works along with `--acceptCertificate` if we pass the parameter like below one

```
jss deploy app --acceptCertificate 89:17:0D:35:FB:F6:FC:3E:8E:E5:9A:22:CE:6C:83:81:8C:DE:76:DD -c -d
```

This worked for me with Sitecore XP 9.3