# Unable to get local issuer certificate with Sitecore JSS Create

Tags: jss, npm

I am trying to create `JSS` app locally however getting below error while running the Sitecore JSS creates command.

```
Error:Unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Command: jss create appname react

I am using the following versions on my local.

```
Sitecore Version: 9.2
JSS Version: 12.0
Node Version: 12.18.3
NPM Version:  6.14.6
```

Please help me how I can resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Alok...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected response from import service: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16401/unexpected-response-from-import-service-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certi)

Comment: Can this question please me reopened, this is not a duplicate. This question is about `jss create`, and the other question is about `jss deploy`, and it's totally different issues.

Answer (score 2):

The `jss create` command simply clones [one of these starter projects](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/tree/dev/samples) from the public jss repo. So errors when running this command are usually caused by GitHub being blocked due to a security policy.

If adding the Sitecore JSS repo to list of permitted access points is not an option with your company, you have the following options:

1. When you run `jss create [project-name] react` - in this example `react` is not a magic string; it is simply the name of a starter project. You can do this for a starter project on your local machine, too. Copy the entire folder of the starter you want to use ([one of these](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/tree/dev/samples)) to your machine, and run `jss create [project-name] [starter-name] --source ./path/to/starter`. This option is quick and will solve the issue on your local machine, but…
2. if you need a company-wide fix, then the following approach is better. Clone the starter to your company’s GitHub org (or wherever your company stores it’s repos, which aren’t blocked by the security policy). Then use `jss create <appname> <starter-name> --repository githubusername/reponame --branch branchname`.

Comment: It works for me. thanks @Anastasiya.